# What's the best way to intersect a box shape layer?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes

I'm attempting to create a login box based on the below, but with a line (in the same style as the outer stroke) dividing the two sections. Is the best way to do this to literally draw a line as a new shape layer through the middle of the box?

I'm wondering if there might not be a better way involving combining paths, or something that would make the whole thing into one shape...

Any advice appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I would totally draw a line with Line tool and put it in a Clipping mask with the "login box", assuming that the line is supposed to go all the way across. That would be fast and it would look good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. There's no other way. You need at least 2 shapes. Either a top-box shape and a bottom-box shape. Or a full shape and a line to divide.